# Python Flask Refresh table every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, dom-events

I have posted my flask code below. I want to refresh table **data** every 60 seconds. `Setinterval` function is included in html . But however its not refreshing. I am not figuring out exact issue in ajax/Javascript. Please somebody can help to figure out the issue.

**App.py:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dsfd'
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'pwd'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
eachcur = ["A","B","C","D"]

@app.route('/', methods= ['GET'])     
def display_deals():

 
    conn = mysql.connect()
    c = conn.cursor()
    data = ((),)
    for curren in eachcur:
      query = "SELECT * from "+curren+" ORDER BY Currid DESC LIMIT 1"
      c.execute(query)
      data = data + c.fetchall()

    conn.close()
    

    return render_template("dashboard.html", data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**dashboard.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
<script>
 setInterval(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
 })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $("#table-box").val(data)
   });
  }, 1000 * 60); 
  </script>
<table border="2" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5" id="table-box" >
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
    {% for d in row %}
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Console Output:

```
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:5000/".
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):7
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):6
17:21:45.516 jquery.min.js:4 [Violation] 'load' handler took 334ms
```

[image: Console snapshot]

[image: Console snapshot - 2]

Comment: The point of stackoverflow is not to provide code for you. There are several ways to achieve this, the easiest being a simple `<META>` tag to reload the whole page. I am sure you can find it using Google. Other methods would include an AJAX call to refresh only the table data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: the tour, and read How-to-Ask. What topics can I ask about

Comment: @Roy Prins  : Thanks for suggestions. I have rephrased question. Now i think someone can figure out bug in html.

Comment: @serdar.sanri : don't comment if you don't understand questions. Everybody are not experts like you. Hope you will understand. Please encourage newbies to raise questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. You are using `.val()` where you should be using `.html()`

   `.val()` is used to set the value of things like input fields, not overwrite entire DOM objects. You should be using `.html()` here instead.
2. You are assigning non-html data to `#table-box`

   Your `for` statement generating the table is only going to run on page load. You need to regenerate all of the table rows in the AJAX  `.done()` handler.

See my example below that fixes both of these issues.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
<script>
 setInterval(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
 })
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    var tableHtml = '';
    for (row in data) {
      tableHtml += '<tr>';
      for (d in row) {
        tableHtml += '<td>' + d + '</td>';
      }
      tableHtml += '</tr>';
    }
    $("#table-box").html(tableHtml)
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
   });
  }, 1000 * 60); 
  </script>
<table border="2" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5" id="table-box" >
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
    {% for d in row %}
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT: It doesn't look like you have a route/controller set up the handle the AJAX request to `POST` `/`. You should try something like this:

```
@app.route('/json', methods= ['GET'])     
def display_deals_json():
  conn = mysql.connect()
  c = conn.cursor()
  data = ((),)
  for curren in eachcur:
    query = "SELECT * from "+curren+" ORDER BY Currid DESC LIMIT 1"
    c.execute(query)
    data = data + c.fetchall()
  conn.close()
  return json.dumps(data)
```

You will need to update your AJAX command to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/json",
})
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion , but still issue is not solved. It remains static page. I am using google chrome. Below is output of flask debugger.   * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 900-414-213
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 12:41:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 12:41:38] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 12:46:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: It's not flask that isn't working. Show the browser console output.

Comment: Here is browser console output - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at localhost/:6  . Error at  $.ajax({

Comment: No errors after using: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">;.. BUT page is remains static. its not refreshing every minute.

Comment: Looks like data is getting null.  Its not entering for loop in below code snippet: function( data ) {
    var tableHtml = '';
    for (row in data) {

Comment: I've updated my answer to include`console.log(data)` on the first line of `.done()` to see the data and also added a `.fail()`. Run it again and update your question with the entire console output.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion. Posted console output in question. I am getting output  like, 0 . 01, 012, 0123 in html display

Comment: @ Jim Wright  In console i am able to see correct output. But Final display is showing  0123.. I have attached snapshot. Please check.

Comment: Problem is its returning complete page instead of only data... I have attached snapshot2. Please check

Comment: The AJAX request is a `POST` to `/`. You should be returning `JSON` data from there. Do you have a route set up for that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example route/controller that should work. You will need to update the URL your AJAX request is calling as well.

Comment: Thanks Jim Wright. its works like a charm. only thing is data is displaying in single column(each character). I will check this issue. I accepted your answer.

Comment: You may need to set `type` to `json` in the Ajax request. Other than that check what data is coming back and good luck!